# If pg_dump with -o is enough?

Tags: postgresql

Postgres says using pg_dump with -o switch keeps the OIDs of each row and it is useful for those applications that count on OIDs.

I have a may be trivial question. Does it mean if we get dump by -o, we can be sure never we lose anything? In other words if getting OIDs included backups could be harmful in some cases? Or just uses more space?

Thanks

Comment: Can you define your understanding of "we can be sure never we lose anything"?

Comment: I am an admin of a pg cluster and should get regular backups of DBs. I'm not sure if users of DBs count on OIDs or not. So I want to get backup in a safe way.

Comment: As far as i know - no. user IDs are something different. Check here for more info about OID: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype-oid.html

Comment: If your app relies on `OID`s it should be fixed. Really.